# How to set/rename of audio while storing in SD card?

Tags: android, audio, set, sequence

I am creating one application which record voice and when i click on StopRecording button,
it store in SD card/Internal memory. But while storing it take random name like  `sound1356543`. But i need to set name on user choice or sequence wise like
MyAudio1
MyAudio2
MyAudio3
MyAudion
How can i do this? Here is my code for reference.

```
File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();         

        audiofile = File.createTempFile("Recording", ".3gp", sampleDir);                    
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

How to set name to audio file.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the filename of audiofile? What if you just change it's path?

Comment: it take a random name and i want to assign name to audio file on user demand.....

Answer (score 0):

remove this line and then check

```
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
```

I had the same issue like this.